# Remove grid effect in density2d ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a 2d density plot with data about age (y axis, integer values, 0-100) and hour (x axis, integer values, 0-23)

```
ggplot(Joined_Data, aes(x=hora, y=edad) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(density)), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  theme(
    legend.position='none'
  )
```

This is the result:

[image]

***I need to REMOVE the vertical rack effect. How do I get it?***

NOTE: My data has a million and a half rows. If I SAMPLE them, and use only the sample for the graph:

```
set.seed(42)
joined_data_sample <- Joined_Data %>% sample_n(5000)
ggplot(joined_data_sample, aes(x=hora, y=edad) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(density)), geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  theme(
    legend.position='none'
  )
```

Then the vertical lines dissapear

[image]

But the geom_bin2d() or the geom_hex() keep showing this problem

[image]

Thanks! :)

Comment: It looks like you need to increase the bandwidth. Try adding `adjust = 2` to your `stat_density_2d` call. Increase this number until the bands are no longer visible. Essentially this is a 2d version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76827513/why-do-some-violin-plots-of-continuous-data-look-wavy/76828018#76828018), with a similar solution

Comment: @AllanCameron, THANKS! It worked like charm! Please, repost your comment as an answer, so I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have many thousands of samples along a continuous variable that has been rounded to the nearest integer, you can run into problems because the automatically-selected smoothing bandwidth becomes too narrow. Normally, decreasing the bandwidth as the sample size increases is a good thing, because it improves resolution of your density plot and prevents unrealistic tails on either side of your data. However, if your data is rounded, the bandwidth can become too narrow to smooth out the gaps between the rounded values.

As an example, look what happens when we try to get a density curve for the (integer-only) Poisson distribution with `lambda = 20`. With 1,000 or even 10,000 samples, the result is a smooth curve, but at 100,000 samples the bandwidth becomes so narrow that we start to get spikes at the integers. The problem gets even worse with one million samples:

```r
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(density(rpois(1000,    20)))
plot(density(rpois(10000,   20)))
plot(density(rpois(100000,  20)))
plot(density(rpois(1000000, 20)))
```

[image]

What you are seeing is essentially a 2D version of this problem. We can replicate it as follows:

```r
set.seed(1)

Joined_Data <- data.frame(
  hora = rep(0:23, each = 5000),
  edad = rgamma(12e5, 3 + rep(0:23, each = 5000)/5, .5))

ggplot(Joined_Data, aes(x=hora, y=edad) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(density)), 
                  geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

[image]

Here, the stripes are equivalent to the spikes on the density plots above.

To get rid of the stripes, we simply increase the calculated bandwidth. We can do this by adding `adjust = 2` to the `stat_density_2d` call:

```r
ggplot(Joined_Data, aes(x=hora, y=edad) ) +
  stat_density_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(density)), adjust = 2,
                  geom = "raster", contour = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks A LOT! Not only for the solution, but for the absolutely GREAT explanation!